# Native Audio in Browsers

Tags: html, audio, browser, native, local

I'm playing audio via the audio tag HTML5. Is my computer supplying support for this audio format or is the browser?

http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

This link is saying certain browsers supply codex for certain formats, so does this mean that the browser is supplying these codex-es?

Comment: "Codices." In case you were wondering. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Some browsers delegate all multimedia related stuff to the system's multimedia stack (i.e. Safari and QuickTime), others have support for only certain formats build-in.
See http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#what-works.

Answer (score 0):

> This link is saying certain browsers supply codex for certain formats,
>   so does this mean that the browser is supplying these codex-es?

Yes, that's exactly what it means. The codec is built-in the browser.

Comment: any legit links to further this? :S